# Default application used for "open folder" in popup menu

Tags: arch-linux, directory, i3, ranger

When I enter, for instance, `xdg-mime query filetype Video/movie.mkv`, the output is `video/x-matroska`; if I then enter `xdg-mime query default video/x-matroska`, the output is `mplayer.desktop`, and that is indeed the application used when I enter `xdg-open Video/movie.mkv`. The same holds for other filetypes for which I've set specific default applications.

On the other hand, nothing happens when I click on "Open Dropbox Folder" in Dropbox' tray icon popup menu, or when I do right-click and "Open folder" on a file in Transmission's list of downloaded files; so, I would expect that no application is associated with directories.

With this in mind, what I've tried so far is to run `xdg-mime query filetype Video`, which returns `inode/directory` and, in turn, run `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`, which returns `ranger.desktop`, my file manager. This sounds quite what I would have expected if everything worked, but this is not the case.

Why nothing happens when I click on "open folder" *et similia* in popup menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your [ranger.desktop](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/doc/ranger.desktop) file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ranger
Comment=Launches the ranger file manager
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Exec=ranger
Categories=ConsoleOnly;System;FileTools;FileManager
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

ranger is a terminal application, you have to run e.g. `xterm -e ranger`. You can see what is happening, when you use i3menu and type `ranger` or `xterm -e ranger`.

<s>There is the line `Terminal=true` which has this effect but you probably miss the configured terminal application.</s>

Actually it seems `Terminal=true` is somehow not working as expected. But @Hanlon documented a workaround at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1270462/how-to-make-firefox-open-cli-app-in-specified-terminal/1270823#1270823).

Comment: Where should I find this default desktop file? By i3menu are you referring to any program I use to run applications or to a specific one?

Comment: You can list all files of a package with: `pacman -Ql ranger`. Use `$mod+d` to test the commands: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3#Application_launcher

Comment: (Thank you for the `pacman` tip!) Well, I don't use `dmenu`, but `rofi` in its place, but I think it's same, isn't it? Indeed, when I run `xterm -e ranger` (actually `urxvt`) from inside `rofi`, `ranger` correctly opens.

Comment: I could not find the correct way to use urxvt with xdg-terminal. It seems that Trilby and Progandy did not find it too: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232051